# How to make query to find past six months date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am stuck in a problem where I want to make query to find past six months date.

I have a scenario in which I want the sum of quantity weekly, which I have achieved but I want to make a query which can find the date from current date to past six month date so how can i achieve it mongodb.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
db.rxTable.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            rxDate: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$rxDate"
                }
            },
            quantity: {
                $toInt: "$quantity"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $week: '$rxDate' },
            data: {
                $addToSet: "$$ROOT",
            },
            sales: {
                $sum: "$quantity"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

I  have also added my query down below.

For example I have tried this scenario in javascript in console but I want it in mongodb.

Here I am posting my example i tried in console.

```js
var sixMonths = 1.577e+10;

sixMonths
15770000000

Date.now()
1589292791593

var current = Date.now();
undefined

current-sixMonths
1573522803658

Date(current-sixMonths)
"Tue May 12 2020 19:43:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Date(current-sixMonths)
"Tue May 12 2020 19:44:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

new Date(current-sixMonths)
Tue Nov 12 2019 07:10:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

new Date()
Tue May 12 2020 19:55:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   /** $$NOW gives you current date */
  {
    $project: { sixMonthOldDate: { $subtract: [ "$$NOW", 15770000000 ] } }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sZ-COjFVU0X)

Comment: Its giving me one date behind today is 13th may and in playground its showing 12th november

Comment: @Ronak07 : Even `console.log(new Date()) & console.log(new Date(Date.now() - 15770000000))` does the same :-)

Comment: Hey @whoami is there any alternate way to solve it so I can get correct date

Comment: @Ronak07 : I live in a place where there are a lot of factors that impact the result, So what is the exact issue is that something like you're getting same time but not the date ? Can you give us sample..Why are you not passing this date as an input to query from code ?